# How to extract frame from mpeg-ts segments using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I use ffmpeg to convert video into MPEG-TS segments for HLS.  How can I then extract image from these MPEG-TS files for use as static "cover page".   I would like to either extract the first or the last frame as JPEG image from the TS file.

Comment: Extracting the first frame of the first TS file should not be a problem (I think), because the first frame is a key frame. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select any frame based on its time position.

```
    ffmpeg -i INPUT -ss 00:00:00.00 -vframes 1 OUTPUT
```